# Restarting Rotation Animation after stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

After lots of changes/trying things etc, I've gotten to a stage where I truly am stuck...

I have a rotating `UIImageview` which infinitely rotates until the screen in pressed... at which point, if the rotation value matches a certain value (landed on a target in the game), the target moves and the game continues... Should you over shoot the target after pressing the screen, the game is over. Simple game.

My trouble is, after you get GameOver and the animation has stopped, I have a `UIButton` appear on screen, which takes you back to the same `ViewController` using `module`. (I've done this for many apps and it works fine).

Except, this time, say you scored 4 (hit 4 targets), then missed the 5th and its GameOver, when you press the button to restart the initial ViewController (basically reloading ViewDidLoad), the animation won't start... even though the scores and other things reset correctly...

This is how I implement the animation:

```
- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.0f
                          delay: 0.0f
                        options: options
                     animations: ^{
                         Hand.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(Hand.transform, M_PI / 30);
                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             if (animating) { //if, keep spinning
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                             } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) { //final spin
                                 //[self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut dir:direction];
                             }
                         }
                     }];
}

- (void) startSpin {
    [Hand.layer removeAllAnimations];
    if (!animating) {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
    }
}

- (void) stopSpin {
    animating = NO;
    inGame = NO;
}
```

I've tried `removeAllAnimations` in various places, thinking maybe it was that... but I don't see why, if the ViewDidLoad is recalled/ViewController reset and you're back to the beginning, why the animation doesn't restart?

The reason I chose this method of rotation is because I could track the rotation value and store it and so I could restart the animation, or so I thought...

Comment: I don't see how`spinWithOptions` is ever called. Also, is `animating` YES or NO at the point of failure? You need to do some debugging with stepping and breakpoints and figure out what's going on.

Comment: `spinWithOptions` is called in `-(void) startSpin`, which is called in the `ViewDidLoad`...

Comment: Are you sure that viewDidLoad is called multiple times? Maybe you should put your call to startSpin in viewWillAppear

Comment: Could this be because your view is never released? You are capturing `self` strongly in the completion block which may be leading to a retain cycle. If so, the second `viewDidLoad` would be called on a new instance of your view and not the one you are expecting.

Comment: How do you release views?